# How to check if email exists, except the user who is requesting?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jwt

I need to check if **email is unique**, but that **shouldn't include the user's email who's requesting**.

For profile edit, when user **edits profile** without changing his email (eg. user@example.com) it gives unique error message added by custom validation `@UniqueCheckEmail`.

**Model class:**

```
public class UserProfileRequest {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email is required")
    @Email(message = "Email is invalid")
    @Column(unique = true)
    @UniqueCheckEmail     // Custom validation
    private String email;
```

**Validator constraint class:**

```
public class EmailConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueCheckEmail, String> {

/* other code */

@Override
public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {          
    boolean status = true;      
    try {
        Optional<UserInfo> userInfo =  userInfoService.findByEmail(email);  
        logger.info(userInfo.toString());
        logger.info("User email present? " + userInfo.isPresent());         
        status = !userInfo.isPresent();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //logger.info("Email NullPointerException --> " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //logger.info("Email unique check Exception --> " + e.getMessage());
    }       
    if (!status) {
        String messageTemplate = "Email already exists";            
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(messageTemplate)
               .addConstraintViolation()
               .disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    }
    return status;
}
```

}

Is there any way I can get JWT token and user details within this `isValid` method?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can autowire the `HttpServletRequest` and access the request headers / cookies / session.

```
public class EmailConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueCheckEmail, String> {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest request;

  // rest of code

}
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks a lot! :)